# Maximality preserved under integral extension???

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

I am very confused. I have "proved" that if $A \subseteq B$ is an integral extension and $I \subseteq A$ is maximal an $J \subseteq B$ is an ideal (not necessarily prime) with $J \cap A = I$, then $J$ is maximal. In particular, this implies $IB$ is maximal if $I$ is. But this is absurd as $(x^2+1)$ is maximal in $\mathbb{R}[x]$ but its extension is not maximal in $\mathbb{C}[x]$ as $(x^2+1) \subsetneq (x-i) \subsetneq \mathbb{C}[x]$. And $\mathbb{C}[x]$ is an integral extension of $\mathbb{R}[x]$ as $\mathbb{C}$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{R}$. My "proof" went something like this:

First we always have $ IB = (J \cap A)B   \subseteq J$. Then because integrality is preserved under quotients, $B/IB$ is an integral $A/I$ algebra. Since $I$ is maximal, $A/I$ is a field. Since integrality preserves fields, $B/IB$ is a field. Since $IB \subseteq J$, by the correspondence theorem $J/IB $ is an ideal in $B/IB$. It is proper as $J$ is proper. Since the only proper ideal of a field is $(0)$ it follows that $J = IB$. Thus $B/J$ is a field and so $J$ is maximal.

This shows that extensions preserve maximality as we have the following:

We always have $I \subseteq IB \cap A$. Since $I$ is proper, $1 \not\in I$ and so $1 \not\in IB$ and thus $1 \not\in IB \cap A$. Thus $IB \cap A$ is a proper ideal and because $I$ is maximal we have $I = IB \cap A$. Thus $IB$ is maximal.

What am I doing wrong here? The argument is sound as far as I can tell. Perhaps there's something wrong with my counterexample?

Comment: A *domain* integral over a field is a field.

Answer (score 1):

It is not true that integral extensions of fields are fields. For instance, $\Bbb F\times\Bbb F$ is an integral extension of $\Bbb F$ by map $\Bbb F\hookrightarrow\Bbb F\times \Bbb F$, $x\mapsto (x,x)$, but it is not a field.